# google colabroratoryでのgmail 認証エラーについてご教授ください

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

google colabroratoryを利用してのgmail APIの利用でエラーが発生して、困っております。エラーとなっている状況は次の通りで、どなたかご教授をお願いできないでしょうか。

google のサンプルをほぼそのまま利用して、実行しようとしております。
サンプルコードの以下部分で、エラーが発生している状況です。

creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0 )

エラー内容はcould not locate runnable browserと表示されます。
WEBで検索などをしたのですが、どのように解決してよいかわからず、ご教授頂けないでしょうか。

■サンプルコード

```
import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly"]


def main():
  """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
  Lists the user's Gmail labels.
  """
  creds = None
  # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
  # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
  # time.
  if os.path.exists("token.json"):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file("token.json", SCOPES)
  # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
  if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
      creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
      flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
          "credentials.json", SCOPES
      )
      creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open("token.json", "w") as token:
      token.write(creds.to_json())

  try:
    # Call the Gmail API
    service = build("gmail", "v1", credentials=creds)
    results = service.users().labels().list(userId="me").execute()
    labels = results.get("labels", [])

    if not labels:
      print("No labels found.")
      return
    print("Labels:")
    for label in labels:
      print(label["name"])

  except HttpError as error:
    # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from gmail API.
    print(f"An error occurred: {error}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: token.jsonをどのようにして取得したか追記すれば、さらに良い回答もらえるかもです。以下推測です。認証がOAuthとなっているため、ブラウザが起動しパスワード入力を必要としているところ、GoogleColabはブラウザを起動する機能がないため、エラーとなっていると思われます。対策は、Windows上もしくはWSL上で実行する。もしくはGoogleCloudPlatformからサービスアカウントを作成し、サービスアカウントで認証するよう変更する。たしかGoogleアカウントの認証設定は２段階認証にしなければならない制約があったと記憶しています。

Comment: もしくは、デスクトップアプリで、トークンファイル（OAuth クライアント ID ）を作成しても、うまくいくかと思います。（URLが表示されるので、自分でブラウザを起動し、そのURLへアクセスし認証します。）